# Sello digital con python

Tags: python, pdf

Un saludo para todos!!

Estoy elaborando unos documentos en pdf mediante python, y para darle una validez formal, se quiere incluir un sello digital compuesto por una cadena de texto, en donde propiamente hay una clave o sello único para cada documento, básicamente son constancias de asistencia a un evento académico, por lo que cada constancia debe de tener un sello único.

Si nos piden cotejar que la constancia de Gustavo Pérez Pérez es válida y auténtica, se realizaría mediante el sello digital único, del tipo:

> `2016-06-18||f90979b330be2df2bbb80452930ae719||ASISTENCIA||GUSTAVO+PEREZ+PEREZ||XLII||CONGRESO||NACIONAL||`

hay datos que corresponden a la fecha, el sello digital (que es lo que quiero generar mediante python) y otros datos.

¿Alguna idea con la que pueda iniciar para generar el sello digital?

Agradezco de antemano sus aportaciones.

Reciban un cordial saludo.
Gustavo.

Comment: ¿El sello en este caso tiene algún significado o es simplemente aleatorio?

Comment: Gracias por preguntar @Alberto Caso, de hecho mi idea es que sea una combinación del nombre de la persona: capitalizar los campos y agregarle ya sea un dato adicional como la fecha o el nombre del evento, de esta forma cada sello sea único.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, lo que estás intentando es implementar una firma electrónica, de forma que para dato puedas obtener el hash del dato que verifica que no hay cambios desde que se generó.

Siendo así, la firma electrónica se implementa, en su formato más sencillo, mediante  una función hash (la puedes hacer usando el módulo hashlib) que usará esa llave para generar la firma al pasar por tu función hash(). Si quisieses añadir seguridad, podrías usar llaves personales que se usarían junto con el dato en la función hash(), de forma que sólo la combinación de la firma y el dato obtienen la cadena hash correcta.

Para obtener el hash más sencillo, simplemente obten una representación de cada registro (para todos los campos), y haz algo similar a lo que muestran aquí: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Verás que si guardas ese hash, cambias un dato en el registro, y vuelves a obtener el hash, habrá cambiado y ya no serán iguales.

Comment: Muchas gracias @mydaemon creo que con esta función podré generar la cadena que necesito!!